# Need to stop a service in aws ec2 instance just before it reboots

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to write a script in python which stops a service running in EC2 instance just before it reboots. 
What should be the approach here?

Suppose service name is abc.

to manually stop this service, I execute:

```
  service abc stop
```

I want to automate this before instance goes for reboot.

Help me with this

Comment: If it's a service then it should stop automatically while the node is shutting down

Answer (score 1):

The cron scheduler allows you to use `@reboot` in place of a schedule string.  So, write your script and then `crontab -e` and add the following:

```
@reboot /path/to/python /path/to/reboot_script.py
```

For the reboot script, python isn't really your best choice.  I would write it using a bash script, looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

service abc stop
```

If you must use python, you could use invoke:

```
from invoke import run
run('service abc stop', hide=True, warn=True)
```

Edit:

To run this BEFORE reboot, make a shell script called `K99kill_service` and add it to your `/etc/rc6.d` directory.  These scripts are executed before reboot or shutdown.  It's important that it is named as above to make sure it runs at the right time and doesn't interfere with other shutdown scripts.

Comment: using @reboot , will this execute before reboot start? Because after reboot the service should automatically come up. I only want service to stop before reboot starts

Comment: No.  Does your service not stop on reboot?  If you need before reboot, make a shell script as above and name it something like `K99kill_service` and put it in your `/etc/rc6.d` directory.  These scripts are executed before reboot, but it sounds like you may have another deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy : https://opensource.com/life/16/11/running-commands-shutdown-linux

See the link, it explains in very much detail on, How to shutdown services in linux before shutdown for both SysVinit and Systemd ?